# What role should my user have in order to reset MFA with powershell?

Tags: powershell, roles

I doing a script that resets de MFA of a specific user. However the user must have a specific role in order to do this, I'm not sure if I should give the user Authentication Policy Adminitrator or just Authentication Adminitrator. What's the difference betwwen the two? Can the Authentication Policy Adminitrator reset the mfa of specific users?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Authentication Policy Administrator: Can create and manage all aspects of authentication methods and password protection policies.

Authentication Adminitrator: Can access to view, set and reset authentication method information for any non-admin user.

---

In your case Authentication Adminitrator should be enough.

---

For more info see

https://learn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/azure/active-directory/roles/permissions-reference#authentication-administrator